# How do I fix a Delphi installation when "repair" doesn't work?

Tags: delphi, installation, repair

I have lost many settings of the IDE, the IDE is not compiling, and other issues. I wanted to repair the installed product (Delphi XE2 Architect). But when I did this, the installer *removed* lots of files in the installation folder, even bds.exe.

I don't want to uninstall and reinstall.

I have also Delphi XE3 installed, and had the same problem, but I uninstalled it and installed it again, and now it's working.

How do I repair this?

Comment: I keep registry backups of the Embarcadero\BDS\# keys under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` and `HKEY_CURRENT_USER`. That, and the contents of my user (not system) BPL and DCP folders, and I can restore pretty easily even if the install failed. But yea, reinstall is safe, if yours failed, perhaps your media or download is corrupt.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have attempted a repair install without success then you only have one option left. Uninstall and reinstall.

Comment: So, let's uninstall !

Comment: FYI, the most of the settings are stored in the user portion of the registry, so a repair would not have helped you out in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

The repair works fine, and shouldn't interfere with your XE3 install. If your IDE is broken to the point that you can't compile, a reinstall is probably the only way to fix it.  A repair or reinstall should also leave your third-party components installed, as it doesn't replace anything in the registry.

(This is really a vendor support question, BTW, and since it's related to installation you can open a free support case at [Embarcadero Support](http://support.embarcadero.com). The question isn't really appropriate for StackOverflow.)

Comment: Thank you, but waiting for support to answer, I prefer uninstall so, and reinstall ! This will be a nice clean for IDE and components updates !